# sklearn cosine similarity :: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'metrics'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cosine-similarity

```
ur[5][8]=
[[0,3,4,0,0,0,5,0],
[4,5,0,0,0,0,3,0],
[0,4,0,3,0,0,1,4],
[2,0,5,0,0,0,3,0],
[0,0,0,5,0,0,0,4]]
```

0 means movie not rated
i want to predict the rating of the unrated movie of each user using cosine similarity and after calculating similarity I pick up k most similar user and predict according to that

but how to calculate the cosine similarity using inbuilt function in skearn library or any other

```
code:
similar=[[0] * 5 for i in range(5)]
print similar
for x in range(0,5):
    for y in range(0,5):
        similar[x][y] = sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity(ur[x],ur[y])

error :
runfile('C:/Users/Nitin/cf/first.py', wdir='C:/Users/Nitin/cf')
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-18-e55296403aad>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Nitin/cf/first.py', wdir='C:/Users/Nitin/cf')

  File "C:\Users\Nitin\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 880, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Nitin\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 87, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "C:/Users/Nitin/cf/first.py", line 23, in <module>
    similar[x][y] = sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity(ur[x],ur[y])

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'metrics'
```

What to pass in cosine_similarity or how to do this correctly

Answer (score 4):

you need to import the module to use it.

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
```

OR

```
import sklearn
# to use it like 
sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity(ur[x],ur[y])
```

Then use it.

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

ur = [[0,3,4,0,0,0,5,0],
[4,5,0,0,0,0,3,0],
[0,4,0,3,0,0,1,4],
[2,0,5,0,0,0,3,0],
[0,0,0,5,0,0,0,4]]

similar=[[0] * 5 for i in range(5)]
print(similar)
for x in range(0,5):
    for y in range(0,5):
        similar[x][y] = cosine_similarity(ur[x],ur[y])

similar
```

output:

```
[[array([[ 1.]]),
  array([[ 0.6]]),
  array([[ 0.37097041]]),
  array([[ 0.80295507]]),
  array([[ 0.]])],
```

Comment: @NitinJain you are welcome. Please consider tick or up-voting if it solved your problem :)